# How can I document a dynamic field using ReDoc?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, redoc

I have a dynamic field defined on a request object like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Some description of this field
/// <example>17.5 or MyString in some cases</example>    
/// </summary>
public dynamic MyField { get; set; }
```

However, in our docs, the fields is showing up as:

```
myField    object (Object) Nullable
```

Is there a way to add a more user-friendly description to this field using ReDoc?  I'd at least like ReDoc to honor the example text.  Note - this is in a dotnet core API using Swashbuckle.

Comment: Do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net (or something else) to generate your API definition?

Comment: We use Swashbuckle.

Comment: Why dynamic why? can we all get along ... my best guess would be to hack the resulting swagger doc with an `IDocumentFilter` not sure what more "user-friendly description" you can do (other than changing the type to just string)